# Python does not always read the line completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline

I have a file which has format like:

```
...
[1, 2, 10, 15, 22]_[18, 23]-0
[0, 2, 10, 21, 23]_[9, 10]-1
[0, 9, 13, 14, 18]_[7, 13]-1
[8, 11, 12, 13, 23]_[8, 11]-1
...
```

I am reading the file with `open(file_path).readlines()`

I want to split the content by '-'. I have a for loop and split function on each line. The code is like:

```
file_path = os.path.join(file_directory, file_name)
file_lines = open(file_path, 'r').readlines()
for line in file_lines:
   var1 = line.split('-')[0]
   var2 = line.split('-')[1]
```

The code breaks in the middle with error of `list index out of range`

When I print the line to debug what is happening, it prints lines correctly except the one that has error; `[8, 11, 12, 13, 23` in this example. When I run it again, some times it won't fail, but some times it fails in another line.

I also tried:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
      ...
```

But got the same result.

I was wondering what the issues can be.

Comment: Could you post the full loop code?

Comment: @darshvader, I did.

Comment: Please correct your code, `.split(-)` will give a syntax error.

Comment: @Tomothy32, I corrected it. It was typo writing it here.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a memory leak from not closing the file, that's all I can think of. Try this code to see whether closing the file makes a difference.

```
file_path = os.path.join(file_directory, file_name)
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    readlines = f.readlines():
for line in readlines:
    var1 = line.split('-')[0]
    var2 = line.split('-')[1]
```

Comment: I tried it with closing earlier, but did not work if I remember correctly.